# Making a for loop with two conditions to allocate a variable in R, but after completing all iterations the answers is not making sense

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, outliers, stat

Trying to run a for loop on a variable from a data set to find outliers that are below the 25th percentile and above the 99th percentile. I need a new variable outlier = 1 when conditions are satisfied and outlier = 0 in other cases. I've run the code below but it seems like I did something wrong, because at the end of the code when I print outlier it outputs 0, and it can't be right because there are numbers in the data set that satisfy the condition.

This is the code:

```
for (i in income) {
if (i < quantile(income, prob = 0.25)) {
    outlier = 1
  } else if (i > quantile(income, prob = 0.99)) {
  outlier = 1 
  } else {
  outlier = 0
  }
}
print(outlier)
```

Comment: Consider `ifelse` for new column: `df$outlier <- ifelse(df$income < quantile(df$income, prob = 0.25) | df$income > quantile(df$income, prob = 0.99), 1, 0)`. No loop needed.

Comment: Or convert from logical vector: `df$outlier <- as.integer(df$income < quantile(df$income, prob = 0.25) | df$income > quantile(df$income, prob = 0.99))`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the outlier is getting updated in each iteration.  We can create a vector before hand, then loop over the sequence of 'income', update the 'outlier' for each position.

```
outlier <- integer(length(income))
for (i in seq_along(income)) {
if (income[i] < quantile(income, prob = 0.25)) {
    outlier[i] = 1
  } else if (income[i] > quantile(income, prob = 0.99)) {
  outlier[i] = 1 
  } else {
  outlier[i] = 0
  }
}
```

NOTE: This can be done in a vectorized way

```
qnt <- quantile(income, prob = c(0.25, 0.99))
+(income > qnt[1]|income < qnt[2])
```